# PHP 5.6 unset $_SESSION sub array entry

Tags: php, session, unset, array-unset

I got the following function:

```
public function stopWatcherSession($sessionID) {
    if(array_key_exists($sessionID, $_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]['names'] as $v) {
            $ptype = $this->paramTypeFromName($v);
            unset($_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY][$ptype][$v]); //does not work, sets entry to null
        }
        unset($_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]); //does not work, sets entry to null
    }
}
```

As the comments say, the array entry does not get unset, the `array_key_exists()`-function still returns `true`, and if you `var_dump($_SESSION)` you can see, that `$_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]` is null.

How can I unset the variable, so that also the key in the array gets removed?

Things i tried, that did not work:

```
// v1 (tried also for `$_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]` )
$tmp = $_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY][$ptype];
unset($tmp[$v]);
$_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY][$ptype] = $tmp;

//v2
unset($_SESSION[self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]);
session_write_close();
session_start();

//v3 => v1 & v2 combined
$tmp = $_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY][$ptype];
unset($tmp[$v]);
$_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY][$ptype] = $tmp;
session_write_close();
session_start();
```

I could add a crappy hack all over the code to check whether it's `null`, but then »empty« values must be changed to something else (like a predefined const, but thats a nasty workaround and leads to confusion for other devs!)

Anyone got some ideas?

Comment: Empty vals can remain in array and for null checking use `isset`

Comment: If the standard value for 'submitted, but no value entered' is `null` and not in the array is 'not submitted', then it's not a good thing to have still the key there floating around with a `null`-value. Unsetting should solve this...

Answer (score 2):

Got it working:

`unset($GLOBALS['_SESSION'][self::WATCHER_SESSION_KEY][$sessionID]);` does the job.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php says:

> The behavior of unset() inside of a function can vary depending on what type of variable you are attempting to destroy. […] To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the $GLOBALS array to do so

Seems like a classical »PHP behaviour is undefined in some cases«-example.